# TLS server accepts connection from client even client cetificate is not present in servers truststore ? why?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

TLS server accepts connection from the client even client cetificate is not present in server's truststore. Why?

Server Code:

```
tlsContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSL_PROTOCOL);
tlsContext.init(getMyKeyManagers(),null,null);
SSLServerSocketFactory fact = tlsContext.getServerSocketFactory();
tlsServerSock = (SSLServerSocket)fact.createServerSocket();
tlsServerSock.setNeedClientAuth(true);
tlsServerSock.setWantClientAuth(true);
tlsServerSock.bind(objSocketAddress);
```

and start listening on Server socket code

Client Code:

```
SSLContext tlsContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSL_PROTOCOL);
tlsContext.init(getMyKeyManagers(), getMyTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory fact = tlsContext.getSocketFactory();
socket = fact.createSocket();
socket.connect(objSocketAddress);
```

As code depicts there are no TrustManagers added at server side still client authentication is successful. why is so?

Comment: The client certificate is only needed in the server truststore if it is self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked quite a while ago, but still ;-)

Two possible reasons: You haven't set a trust manager so the "installed security providers will be searched for the highest priority implementation of the appropriate factory" (taken from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init(javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[],%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[],%20java.security.SecureRandom))). Maybe you installed a trust manager by accident accepting everything.

Alternatively your client might not attempting to do TLS client-authentication at all because you configured the requirement to be optional by setting `setWantClientAuth` to `true`. This most likely overwrote the setting you've done the line above `setNeedClientAuth` to `true`. The former lets the server tell the client "if you've got a certificate for me, please send it" while the latter says "if you don't have a certificate, don't even try...". If for some reason the configured key manager doesn't provide a certificate and private key for TLS client authentication the TLS handshake will succeed.

Using a TCP sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) should help to see if TLS client authentication is actually taking place. Alternatively you can set the system property `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and read through a whole lot of debug output on STDOUT (see [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) to learn more about that)

Answer (score -1):

if there is no trustmananager, then a client cert is nog needed.

an other posebillity is that one of the issuers of the client certificate is present in the truststore at the server.

Comment: is it like that if truststore @ server side set to NULL then any anonymous client will be able to connect and there will be no client authentication even we have set it to true.